# Scala Regular Expression

Tags: regex, scala

I am having some trouble getting this regular expression just right:

Sample string looks something like this:

```
"li3001easdasfsaasfasdi5ei1409529297ei1409529597ed16:acl_dec_tag_listl15:DEFAULT_CASE_11e18:avc_app_name_statsd29:Generic Search Engine Trafficd4:sizei5875e5:totali5ee16:Odnoklassniki.Rud4:sizei456e5:totali1ee7:Unknownd4:sizei6391e5:totali2ee5:Yahood4:sizei15673e5:totali1ee10:Yahoo Maild4:sizei5982e5:totali1e"
```

I want the string to be grouped like this:

```
(li<digit 1-4>e <string of varying length> i<single digit>e) (<string2 of varying length>)
```

This is my attempt at this regex so far: `(li\d{1,}e.*i\de)(.*)`

I would like only the first occurrence of `li<digits 1-4>e` as well.

Comment: Let me update the sample string. The one I posted it works for

Comment: Updated the sample string, it doesn't group how I want it to. I think because of multiple occurrences of li<>e or i<>e

Comment: I would want this (li3001easdasfsaasfasdi5e, <rest of the string>) however, I get this instead: (li3001easdasfsaasfasdi5ei1409529297ei1409529597ed16:acl_dec_tag_listl15:DEFAULT_CASE_11e18:avc_app_name_statsd29:Generic Search Engine Trafficd4:sizei5875e5:totali5ee16:Odnoklassniki.Rud4:sizei456e5:totali1ee7:Unknownd4:sizei6391e5:totali2ee5:Yahood4:sizei15673e5:totali1ee10:Yahoo Maild4:sizei5982e5:totali1e, <rest of string>)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple mistake. `*` is a [**greedy**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#greedytrap) operator, meaning it will match as much as it can and still allow the remainder of the regex to match. Use `*?` instead for a non-greedy match  meaning "zero or more — preferably as few as possible".

```
(li\d{1,}e.*?i\de)(.*)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val s = "li3001easdasfsaasfasdi5easdasfsafas"
val p = """li(\d{1,4})e([^i]*)i(\d)(.*)""".r
val p(first,second,third,fourth) = s
```

results in:

```
first: String = 3001
second: String = asdasfsaasfasd
third: String = 5
fourth: String = easdasfsafas
```

Not sure if that answers your question, but hope it helps.